# Store the first result value into a variable from sql query in php

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to store the result from an sql query into a variable in my php query. But thing is, it is not working, simply because I am making schoolboy errors and due to my lack of experience in php.

This is my code:

```
<?php
    include "init.php"
    if(!empty($_POST['driverNo'])){
        $driverNoText = $_POST['driverNo'];
        $stmt = "SELECT registrationNo FROM cars WHERE driverNo = ?";
        $result = $conn->prepare($stmt);
        $result->bind_param('s', $driverNoText);
        $result->execute();
        $result->store_result();

        if($result->num_rows > 0){
            $registrationNo = $result["registrationNo"];
            echo $registrationNo;
        }
        else{
            $registrationNo = "";
        }
    }
    else{
        echo "Something went horribly wrong";
    }
?>
```

Please note that as both the registrationNo and driverNo are both unique then the result will either return 0 records (not found) OR just 1 (found).

I just want to store the registrationNo into the $registrationNo, because I need to use that value elsewhere later.

Would mean a lot if someone could help me fix my error

Thanks

Comment: Is this your *full* code or did you omit where you declare `$conn`?

Comment: $conn is from my init.php file. It is the connection

Comment: The problem lies in the line $registrationNo = $result["registrationNo"];

Comment: Yes this is the full code

Comment: Use it as `$result->fetch_array(); $registrationNo = $result["registrationNo"];`

Comment: Im getting "Call to undefined method mysqli_stmt::fetch_array() "

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use `->bind_result()` for that:

```
$result = $conn->prepare( $stmt );
$result->bind_param( 's', $driverNoText );
$result->execute();
$result->store_result();

$result->bind_result( $registrationNo );

while( $result->fetch() )
{
    echo $registrationNo;
}

$result->free_result();
```

Note that the use of `->store_result()` in your example is not necessary (although it is not an error): it doesn't “store the first result”, it store all result set in php side. Your script will work even without using it.

---

- Read more about [bind_result](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-result.php)
- Read more about [store_result](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.store-result.php)

Comment: IT WORKS. THANKS :). Where was I going wrong? Also, how do I cater for if the driverNo is valid or no result is found?

Comment: Compare this script with your own: to store a row result in a variable you have to use `->bind_result`. I don't understand what do you mean about `driverNo` validation.